# images wont line up and the text wont go under the img

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to get some images to line up in my content box, but they wont go side by side. Instead they go on each their line. The text are also supposed to go under the image and not to the right of it. Can anyone see the reason why?

I also need to find a way to get them lined up horizontally even if the text under the image are in different lengths up to 30 characters.

Fiddle link: https://fiddle.jshell.net/jkyq9y0u/

```
<div id="content_box">
  <div id="img">
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

#content_box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* styling for the movie images and titles */

#img {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image_box {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movie_img {
  max-width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Have you noticed the content id in html and content_box in css? probably wont fix it but ...

Comment: Id's **must** be unique

Comment: Yeah the content_box is just a typing error i made in fiddle. its correct in my code. I know id's must be unique. i just copy/pasted it. its not really in use in the styling but in the code they will get named image0, image1 etc when the php code runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `style_title` tag your container that defines the rest of it's content. By making it `inline-block` and styling the inner elements appropriatedly you will get what you need.

```css
#content_box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* styling for the movie images and titles */

#img {
  /*max-width: 60%;
  display: inline-block;*/
}

.image_box {
  display: inline-block;
  width:30%;
}

.style_title
{
  display:inline-block;
}

.movie_img {
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="img">
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div  class="image_box image_id">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div class="image_box image_id">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div class="image_box image_id">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div  class="image_box image_id">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div  class="image_box image_id">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css, you need to put these line:

```
.style_title{
   float: left;
}
```

Float left means the "a" box with fill to left. If it doesn't work, then try this:

```
#img > a{
   float: left;
}
```

Please refer to these tutor:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: It makes the title go under the image but not the images to go side by side. Ive had some bad experiences with float across diffrent browsers so i kinda tryed not to use it as much as possible. But i guess i might have been using it wrong. Can still not get the images to line up tho.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give some positions at some point.

You have  to change your content id to content_box for your css to work unless im missing code.

The element that contains the block should have a position;

The element displayed inline should have a relative position;

What ever is inside the inline block can then have an absolute position or else;

Exemple :

```
<div id="content_box">
 <div id="my_block">
 <div id="my_block_content">something</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The CSS;

```
#content_box{
 position:fixed;   /*Could be anything as long its there*/
}

#my_block{
 position:relative;   
 width : 300px;
 height : 400px;
 display: inline-block;
}

#my_block_content{
 position:absolute;     /*Content absolute inside the inline block*/
 top:30px;
 right:0px;
 min-width:95px;
 height:300px;


}
```

Comment: Yeah the content id is my bad. Its content_box in the code. Just a typing error on the fiddle. But when i set position absolute all the images go on top of each other.

Comment: What did you set as absolute?

Comment: i made #content_box position:fixed; #img position:relative; and .image_box absolute.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make some changes in you css.
I've updated your code

```css
#content_box {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 75vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* styling for the movie images and titles */

#img {
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.image_box {
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movie_img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title {
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#content{float: left;width: 100%;}
.style_title{width: 25%;float: left;padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="img">
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
    <a href="link" class="style_title" target="_blank">
      <div id="image_id" class="image_box">
        <img class="movie_img" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BOGNkMzliMGMtMDI5Ni00OTZkLTgyMTYtNzk5ZTY1NjVhYjVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTAzMTY4MDA@._V1_UY209_CR0,0,140,209_AL_.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="title">The Disaster Artist (2017)</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! i used the above example but this would also work!